# pf_ring and libpcap if_index not returning

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, libpcap, pf-ring

I have recently been getting involved with having to utilize pf_ring / libpcap. I have never developed with libpcap or pf_ring so please forgive what might appear to be a silly question, as network programming is semi new to me... In broad terms what I am trying to do is access the if_index for packets received. I currently have a simple raw packet sniffer created with "C" utilizing pf_ring as shown below:

```
#include <pcap.h>
#include <pfring.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXBYTES2CAPTURE 2048


void processRingPacket(const struct pfring_pkthdr* pkthdr, const u_char* packet, const u_char *arg)
{
        int i=0, *counter = (int*)arg;

        printf("Packet Count: %d ", ++(*counter));
        printf("Received Packet Size: %d ", pkthdr->len);
        printf("ifIndex: %d ", pkthdr->extended_hdr.if_index);
        printf("Payload:\n");

        for(i=0; i < pkthdr->len; i++)
        {
            if(isprint(packet[i]))
            {
                    printf("%c ", packet[i]);
            }

            else
            {
                    printf(". ");
            }

            if((i % 16 == 0) && (i != 0) || (i == pkthdr->len-1))
            {
                    printf("\n");
            }
    }

    return;

}

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    char *device = "eth0";  

    printf("Opening Device: %s\n", device); 

    pfring* ring = pfring_open(device, MAXBYTES2CAPTURE, 0);
    pfring_enable_ring(ring);

    pfring_loop(ring, processRingPacket, (u_char*)&count, 1);   

    return 0;
}
```

Looking at the pfring_pkthdr struct within the pf_ring API, I should be able to do the following:

```
pkthdr->extended_hdr.if_index
```

However, when I try to print out the index it just prints 0. I am guessing the if_index is not actually being set, as when I actually call the pf_ring function to get the device if index, I actually receive a value for the specified device:

```
pfring_get_device_ifindex (pfring *ring, char *device_name, int *if_index)
```

The problem is I am trying to view the if_index for each packet, hence within the call back function "processRingPacket" there is no way to generically specify the device. I say generically here because there will be two interfaces capturing packets. Any ideas on what my rookie mistake might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to pass in `PF_RING_LONG_HEADER` as a flag to `pfring_open()`. So it becomes, `pfring_open(device, MAXBYTES2CAPTURE, PF_RING_LONG_HEADER);`

Comment: This did the trick. Figured it had to be something simple. Can't believe I looked over this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If `pkthdr->extended_hdr.if_index` isn't set in the callback function, you can always pass it in to your callback function in the `arg` argument.

```
struct Dev {
   int count;
   int if_index;
};
```

...

```
char *device = "eth0";  
struct Dev dev;
dev.count = 0;
dev.if_index = if_nametoindex(device); //from #include <net/in.h>

printf("Opening Device: %s\n", device); 

pfring* ring = pfring_open(device, MAXBYTES2CAPTURE, 0);
pfring_enable_ring(ring);

pfring_loop(ring, processRingPacket, (u_char*)&dev, 1);
```

And recover that in the callback function:

```
void processRingPacket(const struct pfring_pkthdr* pkthdr, const u_char* packet, const u_char *arg)
{
    struct Dev *dev = (struct Dev*)arg;    
    int i=0, *counter = (int*)&dev->count;
   //and use dev->if_index; whenever you need to.
```

Comment: That is great, if you only capture from one interface or can otherwise keep track of which callbacks are for which interfaces. However, I have to suggest it would be a bit more generic to read the interface number from the captured packets extended headers.

Comment: thuovila: Coincidentally  I am trying to capture on two devices, hence this is why I am trying to grab the ifindex generically to be able to tell the direction of each packet (Ex. is the packet coming in on ethA or is it going out on ethB).

Comment: @matt32 are you calling pfring_loop() twice (e.g. in different threads) in that case, or are you doing something else ? (What do you pass in as the device to pfring_open ?)

Comment: @nos pfring_loop is called once. The device(s) passed in would be something like "eth0,eth1".